# Associate an array of buttons with their resource id

Tags: java, android

I have a 20 buttons in Array, and i need associate every button to their resource id.

I have very little experience in Java and less in Android.

What I do now is this:

```
        botonColor[0] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_01);
        botonColor[1] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_02);
        botonColor[2] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_03);
        botonColor[3] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_04);
        botonColor[4] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_05);
        botonColor[5] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_06);
        botonColor[6] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_07);
        botonColor[7] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_08);
        botonColor[8] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_09);
        botonColor[9] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_10);
        botonColor[10] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_11);
        botonColor[11] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_12);
        botonColor[12] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_13);
        botonColor[13] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_14);
        botonColor[14] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_15);
        botonColor[15] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_16);
        botonColor[16] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_17);
        botonColor[17] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_18);
        botonColor[18] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_19);
        botonColor[19] = findViewById(R.id.newlist_btn_20);
```

My first idea was to replace the text string corresponding to the ID with its numerical equivalent, but the numbers do not follow a specific order and I don't know where to change those numeric literals for others that follow a sequence.

Can someone guide me to do it more appropriately?

Thank you very much and sorry for my English.

Comment: You can put all the buttons in a container and iterate over the container for it's children

Comment: Hi, I feel like you can do it another way,so please provide some code so we can help you and decide for the best way this can be accomplished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually do it like

```
int ids[] = { R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.Button3 };
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
for(int id : ids) {
    buttons.add(findViewById(id));
}
```

Any additional config you want, like setting up click handlers, can go in the loop.  Then you can do buttons.get(index) to get button index.

Comment: Thanks, it is faster and more elegant than my solution.